# Stopping Code In Python Without Break

Tags: python, loops

Is there a way to stop code in Python during a loop without the break function? For example if I'm given a text file that looks like:

```
5 *
7 *
5 *
Limerick
8 A
8 A
5 B
5 B
8 A
Quintain (English)
0 A
0 B
0 A
0 B
0 B
```

How do I stop the loop as soon as it reaches the line that contains all letters (in this case Limerick) without using the break function?

```
for line in file:
    list.append(line) until it reaches Limerick and ignore the rest of the file
```

Basically I want to append the top 3 lines into a list and then stopping the loop without using the break function.

Comment: You want to break out of a loop but you don't want to use the command that exists for expressly that purpose?

Comment: What about a `While` loop ?

Comment: Not up to me. It's for an assignment and we aren't allowed to use breaks. I wouldn't be asking if we could.

Comment: How about `continue`? If the line is `Limerick`, then loop always `continue` until end?

Comment: I can't really understand why one wouldn't be allowed to use breaks.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
f = open('your_file')
my_list= []
for x in f:
    if x.strip() == 'Limerick':
        f.seek(0,2)
    else:my_list.append(x.strip())
print my_list
```

output:

```
['5 *', '7 *', '5 *']
```

In the above code it will append until it found Limerick, f.seek(0,2) will let file to reach end.

you can also use a return:

```
>>> my_list = []
>>> def limeric(f):
...     for x in f:
...         if x.strip() == 'Limerick':
...             return
...         my_list.append(x.strip())
... 
>>> f= open('your_file')
>>> limeric(f)
>>> my_list
['5 *', '7 *', '5 *']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable to control action in loop.

```
my_list = []
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f_i:
    flag = 1
    for line in f_i:
        if flag:
            if line.strip() != 'Limerick':
                my_list.append(line)
            else:
                flag = 0

print(my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this in a function and simply return from the function instead of using break.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a function and `return` will stop the loop:

```
def lines_to_limerick_in(file_path):
    lines = []
    with open(file_path) as file:
        for line in file:
            lines.append(line)
            if 'Limerick' in line:
                return lines
        return lines
```

usage:

```
lines = lines_to_limerick_in(filepath)
```